# React Styling in Props

Tags: reactjs, styling

I did some styling for a material ui button and now I want to move the `style={{backgroundColor}}` part to the top of the function, right before the return.

Does someone know how to do that?

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    backgroundColor: "#05164D",
    transition: "linear 0.5s",
    "&:hover": {
      opacity: 0.9,
      boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(153, 153, 153, .8)"
    }
  }
};

const StyledButton = props => {
  const { classes } = props;
  let customColor = props.customColor || "#05164D";
  let backgroundColor = customColor;

  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton
        className={classes.root}
        {...props}
        aria-label="StyledButton"
        style={{ backgroundColor }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(StyledButton);
```

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is and why you want to move `style`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is important to mention that `{backgroundColor}` is a shorthand for `{backgroundColor: backgroundColor}`. So in ES6 you can simply use the variable name, if the value of the property should be the same as the variable name. This variable is initialized within the curly braces, which wrap the property value. That's why it is `{{ backgroundColor }}`. If you want to initialze the variable above the render you can do it like this.

```
const StyledButton = props => {
  const { classes } = props;
  let customColor = props.customColor || "#05164D";
  let style = { backgroundColor: customColor };

  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton
        className={classes.root}
        {...props}
        aria-label="StyledButton"
        style={style}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```